# Newly added API parameters not showing up in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I just changed my Delete API from this:

```
    // DELETE: api/Doors/0
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete an existing door by id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The ID of the door to be deleted.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        ....
    }
```

To this:

```
    // DELETE: api/Doors/0/0
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete an existing door by id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OrganizationSys">The Organization ID for the door to be deleted.</param>
    /// <param name="id">The ID of the door to be deleted.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int OrganizationSys, int id)
    {
        ....
    }
```

Then in Swagger, the new parameter IS showing up in the Try It section, but it's not showing up in the header.  See screenshot below...

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning all the old .dlls before rebuilding, looks like a caching issue IMO

Comment: @adosi, yep, I already tried that.  No go.

Comment: if swagger is accessing the information from your xml comments, you may need to refresh your xml comments first

Comment: Does the call work? It might be a routing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because in your `RoutingConfig.cs` (or equivalent) only the `id` parameter is set to behave using a `/`, and all other parameters (such as `OrganizationSys`) have to be passed using a `?` or `&`

e.g.: In your xml comment you have

`DELETE: api/Doors/0/0`

But in actuality its

`DELETE: api/Doors/0?OrganizationSys=123`

Perhaps Swagger doesn't recognize query string parameters when creating the headers.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of what I mean (taken from a default ASP .NET MVC web application)

```
// RoutingConfig.cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This default route makes it so the `id` parameter behaves using `/123` as opposed to needing to be passed via `?id=123`.